# Arithmetic sequences

Tags: arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

I am learning about arithmetic progressions and I came across the question: "Prove that there is no infinite arithmetic sequence whose terms are all prime numbers."

I can see that there is no constant difference between all the prime numbers and hence an arithmetic sequence consisting only of prime numbers can't exist. However, I am unsure about how to prove this mathematically.

Comment: Terms in an arithmetic progression have the form $na+b$ for constants $a$ and $b$.  $a$ and $b$ have a common factor, or they are coprime.  Consider these two cases separately.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251258/prime-arithmetic-progression-with-one-fixed-element

Comment: You don't need all the primes to be in it.

Answer (score 2):

Let us suppose this arithmetic sequence exists. Then, let the first term be p, and the common difference is d. Then, the (p+1)th term is p+pd, but it is a multiple of p, so it is composite. But, we assumed all terms are prime. Therefore, no arithmetic sequence has all terms as primes.

Comment: and the $p+nd+n+1$ th term is divisible by the $n+1$ th in general.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another proof. Suppose otherwise, and take an arithmetic progression with only primes. Let its first term be $n$, and its common difference be $d$. Take a prime $p>d$. There exists an integer $a$ such that $$p\mid da+n,$$ namely, $n$ times the modular inverse of $-d$. Therefore, $$d(p+a)+n$$ will be a multiple of $p$ bigger than $p$ in the progression, and we’re done.